# application is using log4j2 but still i am getting the warning message of log4j1

Tags: log4j2

My application is using `log4j2`, but I am still getting the warning message from `log4j1`

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info...

No where log4j1 related configuration is not there. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the Log4j 1.2.x jar is somewhere in the classpath. You can find out where by printing its classpath location:

```
URL location = org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.class
    .getResource(“/org/apache/log4j/Hierarchy.class”);
System.out.println(location);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply ..i have excluded log4j at application level still i am getting the same warning message ...not able to find still from where it is taking

Comment: Have you tried printing out the classpath location like I suggested in the above comment?